# Send email with django and celery inside docker gives OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, smtp, celery

I am trying to send mail through django and celery inside docker, i am using different container for celey and different for django. here is my compose:-

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    expose:
      - 6379

  # Database Postgres
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    volumes:
      - local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: postgres_db

  # Migrations
  migration:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: app:django
    volumes:
      - .:/django
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    depends_on:
      - db

  # Django Application
  app:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/django
    image: app:django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: django_app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    # command: gunicorn HopeAndHappiness.wsgi:application
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
      migration:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  # Celery
  celery:
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    image: app:django
    volumes:
      - .:/django
    command: celery -A HopeAndHappiness worker -l DEBUG
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - app
      - migration

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  local_pgdata:
```

My Dockerfile:-

```
FROM python:slim-buster

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PORT=8000

# Install system packages required by Wagtail and Django.
RUN apt-get update --yes --quiet && apt-get install --yes --quiet --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    libmariadbclient-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /django

# Install the application server.
RUN pip install "gunicorn==20.0.4"

# Install the project requirements.
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
```

My tasks file:-

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import (
    send_mail as django_send_mail,
    send_mass_mail as django_sent_mass_email,
)


@shared_task
def send_mail(
    subject,
    message,
    from_email,
    recipient_list,
    fail_silently=False,
    auth_user=None,
    auth_password=None,
    connection=None,
    html_message=None,
):
    return django_send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        from_email,
        recipient_list,
        fail_silently,
        auth_user,
        auth_password,
        connection,
        html_message,
    )


@shared_task
def send_mass_mail(
    datatuple, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None
):
    return django_sent_mass_email(
        datatuple, fail_silently, auth_user, auth_password, connection
    )
```

I am trying to send email:-

```
send_mass_mail.delay(
    (
        (
            "Email From a client.",
            message_body,
            "from_emai",
            [to_email],
        ),
        (
            "Thank You",
            message_two,
            "from_email",
            [to_email],
        ),
    )
)
```

and got this error(Log of celery cointainer):-

```
2023-08-29 20:55:00 [2023-08-29 20:55:00,843: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-16] Task home.tasks.send_mass_mail[94069995-7cb8-4a96-a7f7-8548c957489b] raised unexpected: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address')
2023-08-29 20:55:00 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
2023-08-29 20:55:00     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
2023-08-29 20:55:00                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
2023-08-29 20:55:00     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
2023-08-29 20:55:00            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/django/home/tasks.py", line 37, in send_mass_mail
2023-08-29 20:55:00     return django_sent_mass_email(
2023-08-29 20:55:00            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 114, in send_mass_mail
2023-08-29 20:55:00     return connection.send_messages(messages)
2023-08-29 20:55:00            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 127, in send_messages
2023-08-29 20:55:00     new_conn_created = self.open()
2023-08-29 20:55:00                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 85, in open
2023-08-29 20:55:00     self.connection = self.connection_class(
2023-08-29 20:55:00                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
2023-08-29 20:55:00     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
2023-08-29 20:55:00                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
2023-08-29 20:55:00     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
2023-08-29 20:55:00                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
2023-08-29 20:55:00     return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
2023-08-29 20:55:00            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
2023-08-29 20:55:00     raise exceptions[0]
2023-08-29 20:55:00   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
2023-08-29 20:55:00     sock.connect(sa)
2023-08-29 20:55:00 OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

also tried to send single mail but got the same error.

I am not able to figure out what is the problem, also send email without celery works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a smtp container with https://github.com/maildev/maildev.
In your docker-compose.yml add the service like that :

```
  smtp:
    image: maildev/maildev
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
      - 1025:1025
```